# In Google cloudbuild.yaml, what is the - | argument?

Tags: google-cloud-build

In Google cloudbuild tutorial the example cloudbuild.yaml uses - | as one of the arguments.

```
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
      if [ -d "environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
...
```

What is the purpose of '- |'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That character is called "Literal Block Scalar" and it is used to span values across multiple lines. Spanning with `|` will include the newlines and any trailing spaces. You can also span with `>` but this will fold new lines to spaces.

Example:

```
include_newlines: |
        exactly as you see
        will appear these three
        lines of poetry     

fold_newlines: >
        this is really a
        single line of text
        despite appearances
```

If you want to know more about the yaml syntax, you can visit [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) for information that may not be included in the cloud build [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config).